# Query many-to-many relationship with linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables Game and Role. When mapping the tables with Entity Framework the table that represents the tables' relationship was not mapped. 
And currently I am trying to extract from the database using LINQ all the game roles under a specific game but I am struggling with the return type of my method.

Is there a different solution to what I am currently trying to achieve with my code?

```
 public List<Game> GetGamesRole(int? gameID)
    {
        using (DbContext db = new DbContext ())
        {
            if (!gameID.HasValue && !roleID.HasValue)
            {
                var query = from game in db.Game select game;
                _games = query.ToList();
                return _games;
            }
            else if (gameID.HasValue)
            {
                var query = db.Game.Join(db.Role, game => game.ID, role => role.ID,
                    (game, role) => new { Game = game, Role = role }).Where(gameRole => gameRole.Game.ID == gameID).ToList();
                _games = query.ToList<Game>();

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the relationship mapped with EntityFramework you don't need to do the join manually, EF will do that for you; assuming you have something like `public List<Role> Roles {get;set;}` on Game, you only need to `.Include(g => g.Roles)` when you query, then each Game will have its list of Roles populated.

Doing the join manually can also work but you'd probably need to do a GroupJoin. But it's much easier to let the framework help you with that, like I described above.

Comment: My Game class does contain list of roles, yes. I tried what you suggested but I am not sure if that is the correct way because I do not seem to get the roles
 







    `var query1 = db.Game.Include("Role").Where(x => x.ID == 
      gameID).ToList();
     _games = query1.ToList<Game>();
     return _games;`

Comment: Try using the Include overload that lets you specify a lambda, that would make it much easier to see any errors. I think the Include argument needs to be the name of the property so "Roles" if that's what the property is named. But again, using the lambda would force you to do it correctly.

Comment: I tried to use this line of code but still does not return roles

`var query1 = db.Game.Where(x => x.ID == gameID).Include(g => g.Role).ToList()`

Comment: Are you sure the relationships are defined correctly? Do you use code first or the designer? If code first do you use model builder?

Comment: I am using Code First from Database which maps down the tables into entities. When I breakpoint, I can see the roles under the specific games but in the response, they are not present

Comment: Under the specific games - so after the call to ToList() you can see the roles in the debugger? That means Entity Framework did its job and populated them. If they get lost somewhere else along the way something else may be to blame. Unless you have lazy loading enabled, don't know too much about that since it's the first thing I usually turn off.

Comment: I don't seem to have LazyLoading. I am not familiar with it, i tried disabling it after  i open my stream but that did not change anything. 

After I call the list and it queries for the specific game, I can see the roles, yes.

Comment: Then continue debugging (step in with F11) until the problem manifests (the roles disappear) and see what else happens along the way. If they're there then obviously... they're there, right? You said 'in the response', if that refers to an HTTP application response a ton of things can happen along the way.

Comment: Currently, I am trying to use Fiddler in order to test my API call

Comment: I tried stepping into and inspecting the vars and the roles remain. They do not get lost anywhere along the path but the json response contains only the games...

Comment: That sounds odd but opens a whole load of additional questions. If you're using WebAPI, are your entities decorated with DataContract/DataMember attributes by any chance? It's one of the few scenarios I can think of where some members are ignored when serializing. But I'm just doing psychic debugging now, aka guessing.

Comment: I found the problem :D It was because I did not include the DataMember under the Role property in Game. I had some problems with that before because it did not want to connect to my service because of virtual properties but now it work. Thank you so much for you help and time!!

Comment: What do you know, psychic debugging actually works sometimes :D

Comment: Do you think I can ask you another question in relation to the current post?

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new one, perhaps with a link back here if it's necessary. Having long comment threads is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty, so if this is incorrect, disregard this answer.

But isn't the problem that your query:

```
db.Game.Join(db.Role, game => game.ID, role => role.ID,
                    (game, role) => new { Game = game, Role = role }).Where(gameRole => gameRole.Game.ID == gameID).ToList();
```

Is not returning a type "Game" Object list? you are doing a join after all. 
I see you are attempting to call the return type "Game" by naming it that way in the Linq expression, but I don't think that quite does what you are hoping for. 
Since a class is already defined as "Game" this will conclift. Especially since the two different classes aren't defined the same.
Try to split up the return types into different methods and see if that doesn't solve your issue.

Either generate a class that holds all the information, but doesn't need all of it. Or generate two different methods for each case, so each has a seperate return type... That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You have lazy loading enabled? If not, try to enable it. 
Be aware that lazy loading bad used can hit the application performance.